# List Item not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

My 4th list item "Contact" is not lining up with the rest of the list items.

The 4th list item contains a few divs and additional styling to create a button that displays my contact information as opposed to redirecting to a different section as the other list items do.

I've tried messing with padding but it messes up when I use a smaller viewport.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?
[image]

```css
.popup {
  width: 350px;
  height: 280px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -200%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, top 1000ms ease-in-out transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.popup.active {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 500%;
  right: 20%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.89, 0.43, 1.19);
}

.popup .icon {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.popup .icon i.fa-solid {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #3a86ff;
}

.popup .title {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.popup .description {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.popup .dismiss-btn {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.popup .dismiss-btn button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #111;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 2px solid #111;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.popup .dismiss-btn button:hover {
  color: #111;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.popup>div {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.popup.active>div {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup.active .icon {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.popup.active .title {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.popup.active .description {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 350ms;
}

.popup.active .dismiss-btn {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 400ms;
}
```

```html
<!-- NavBar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ben</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#Skills">Skills</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#Projects">Projects</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#About">About</a>
        </li>

        <!-- Button Contact modal -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="popup center">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="title">Contact</div>
            <div class="description">
              <p>Email: Pavlovichben@gmail.com </p>
              <p>Phone: (224) 456-2817</p>
            </div>
            <div class="dismiss-btn">
              <button id="dismiss-popup-btn">Dismiss</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="center">
            <a class='nav-link' id="open-popup-btn">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you post some more complete code? The code does not match the screenshot. https://jsfiddle.net/y7cht2vp/

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - and check that the snippet when run shows the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BenPavlovich/matq85oz/1/

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle where you can see the error. The 4th list item doesnt line up with the other ones. I added in additional CSS and JS. The previous code snippet in the question shows the error as well

Comment: the first three itemshave only `a` inside the  4th has much more content inside, also in your fiddle you're nor even linking bootstrap

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have this in my html:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" > Would that not link bootstrap?

Comment: Updated fiddle with all of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/BenPavlovich/matq85oz/4/